# search many min in java

Tags: java, arrays

i'm newbie in java. i have problem search many min in java.
i have a big data. but example data like this.

```
    k[][] =   [74   85  123 
               73   84  122
               72   83  121
               70   81  119
               69   80  118
               76   87  125
               77   88  126
               78   89  127];
```

and i want output like this.

```
min1 = 69    min1 = 80   min1 = 118
min2 = 70    min2 = 81   min2 = 119
min3 = 72    min3 = 83   min3 = 121
```

i use sorting in this data but the results it's not eficient.
someone help me
thx

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what you are asking. Can you clarify problem you are facing? What do you mean by "results it's not efficient"?

Comment: Are you trying to find the three smallest elements in each column?

Comment: @PM77-1 I think that what OP need but his data structure and question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Are you allowed to use TreeMap?

Comment: yeah, iwant find 3 smallestin each column

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general implementation using a helper class for finding the lowest X integers.

With three columns, three instances of the helper class is created, and the data is then iterated to collect the 3 lowest values for each column.

The advantages of this code are:

- Only retains the lowest X values
- Does not need to box the integers
- Uses binary search for improved performance of higher values of X

This means it should be fast and have a low memory footprint, supporting unlimited amounts of data (if streamed).

See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/v0CCri) for demo.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Ideone {
    private static final int MIN_COUNT = 3;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] data = { { 74, 85, 123 },
                         { 73, 84, 122 },
                         { 72, 83, 121 },
                         { 70, 81, 119 },
                         { 69, 80, 118 },
                         { 76, 87, 125 },
                         { 77, 88, 126 },
                         { 78, 89, 127 } };
        // Initialize min collectors
        Min[] min = new Min[data[0].length];
        for (int col = 0; col < min.length; col++)
            min[col] = new Min(MIN_COUNT);
        // Collect data
        for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < min.length; col++)
                min[col].add(data[row][col]);
        // Print result
        for (int i = 0; i < MIN_COUNT; i++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < min.length; col++)
                System.out.printf("min%d = %-5d ", i + 1, min[col].get(i));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
class Min {
    private int[] min;
    public Min(int count) {
        this.min = new int[count];
        Arrays.fill(this.min, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    public void add(int value) {
        int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(this.min, value);
        if (idx != -this.min.length - 1) { // not insert at end
            if (idx < 0)
                idx = -idx - 1;
            System.arraycopy(this.min, idx, this.min, idx + 1, this.min.length - idx - 1);
            this.min[idx] = value;
        }
    }
    public int get(int index) {
        return this.min[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: this code is good. but if i have data is double not integer? how to make it?

Comment: @swatzz are you serious?

Answer (score 0):

Say your data has N rows and M columns

1. Iterate over each column
2. Add all the elements in the column into a minHeap ( min priority queue)
3. Retrieve the first 3 numbers from the minHeap (these will be the 3 mins)
4. Clear the queue and move onto the next column

O(n) space, O(M*N*lg(N)) time